# audioTrack.stop doesn't stop playing audio

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am creating AudioTrack with following definition.

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            44100,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            buffer.length * 2,
                            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    audioTrack.setPositionNotificationPeriod(500);
                    audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(buffer.length);
                    progressListener = new PlaybackProgress(buffer.length);
                    audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(progressListener);
```

When the audioTrack finishes, the following is called to stop the audio and reset the head position.

```
private void resetAudioPlayback() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playbackView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 0;
        playbackView.setLayoutParams(params);
        audioTrack.stop();
        audioTrack.reloadStaticData();
        playImage.animate().alpha(100).setDuration(500).start();
    }
```

The above code works perfectly fine with Android 5.1. But I having issues with 4.4.4. audioTrack.stop() is called but the audio is not stopped, since the reloadStaticData rewinds the audio back to the start position, it replays the audio. but with 5.1, it correctly stops and resets the buffer back to the start of the playback and when play button is pressed, plays from beginning.

Can someone help me how can I this issue with Android 4.4.4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely certain if this will solve your problem, but consider using pause() instead of stop().  By documentation, stop() for MODE_STREAM will actually keep playing the remainder of the last buffer that was written.  You're using MODE_STATIC, but it might be worth trying.

Also (possibly unrelated), consider that write() returns the number of bytes written, so you shouldn't depend on a single write filling the entire buffer of the AudioTrack every time.  write() should be treated like an OutputStream write in that it may not write the entire contents of the buffer it was given, so it's better to write a loop and check how much has been written with each call to write(), then continue to write from a new index in the buffer array until the sum of all the writes equals the length of the buffer.

Comment: Actually, I already tried, audioTrack.pause and flush, the thing is we call reloadStaticData to rewind the track and keep it ready for next play. Here if I call pause and flush, the reloadStaticData does not rewind the audio.